# Spooling problem when sending a print job to a printer via an Electron App on Windows 7

Tags: printing, windows-7, electron, electron-packager, xerox

I've got an Electron Application which I'm compiling to a windows .exe via `electron-packager . --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --overwrite`

The problem I'm facing is when the application, running on Windows 7, sends a print job to a Xerox printer, the print job in the queue has a status of `Spooling` and never changes.

[image: Spooling]

I've tried restarting the `Print Spooler` service via the `Services` panel in windows - this helps me to remove the print job which is stuck, but doesn't allow the print job to print.

A test print (`Print Test Page`) seems to work without getting stuck in the Spooling status.

Why is my HTML document (which consists of an image and text) getting stuck in Spooling status?

Answer (score 0):

Found out why this was happening.

I was launching the electron app from a network/mapped drive (i.e. on virtual box, a drive that was mapped between my host & the virtual machine)

You must launch the electron application from a local drive on the machine, not a network drive

Github comment which directed me to this issue: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/24734#issuecomment-711376100